# Changing interval of which the function $1/(1-x)$ is discontinuous to continuous

Tags: functions, continuity

So I wanted to make sure my example of a problem was correct. I know that the function $y=1/(1-x)$ is discontinuous over the interval $[0,1]\to[0,1]$ (this is format for domain $\to$ range). Am I correct to say that the same function $y = 1/(1-x)$ is continuous if we change the interval to be instead $[0,1) \to [0,1]$.

Comment: The function is not defined at $x=1$, of course it is not continuous on $[0,1]$. And when $x\in[0,1)$, then $\frac{1}{1-x}∈ [1,\infty)$.

Comment: I know that but this function would be wrong as some values are outside the range of [0,1]. That is my mistake did not even realize this.